# CSS - Same maximum height by content applied on all elements No Js

Tags: css, flexbox, height, bootstrap-4

I have multiple cards, and I'd like to obtain the same height for all the cards based on the maximum height obtained by filling the content in the div with the `head` class.
The Cards container is a flex-container, and also the card is structured as a flex-container

I also attached an example image for a better comprehension.
Is it possible to achieve with `css`?

```
<div class="Cards">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="product col-12 col-lg-4 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
            <div class="card-body-wrapper d-flex flex-column">
                <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                    <div class="head">
                        <h4>Card Title</h4>
                        <p class="subtitle">Card Subtitle</p>
                    </div>
                    <p>element 1</p>
                    <p>element 2</p>
                    <p>element 3</p>
                    <a class=" btn"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Not the way the image has set it up, you will need js. Due to each head class is in their own container which means they are not flex items of the same parent

Comment: No.. there is no CSS method (not one) for equalising heights between elements that do not share a parent element. You need JS.

Comment: The card container is flex